# problema con SELECT en java

Tags: java

Tengo un pequeño código en java que antes de meterme información en la base de datos, busca a través de un código si el registro está ya incluido en la base de datos o no. Si lo está lo actualiza y sino lo inserta.

```
boolean isInsert;
            boolean precio_modificado = false;

            try (PreparedStatement ps = con_actu.prepareStatement("SELECT * FROM info_XboxOne WHERE Codigo_juego = ?")) {
                ps.setString(1, code);

                try (ResultSet rs = ps.executeQuery()) {
                    isInsert = !rs.next();

                }
            }

            if (isInsert) { //si se cumple esta condicción significa que el juego no está incluido, con lo que lo metemos
                try(PreparedStatement ps = con_actu.prepareStatement("INSERT INTO info_XboxOne (Juego, DWG, juegos_vault, EA_Access, spotlight, fecha_spotlight, Tipologia, Pertenece, "
                + "Nota, Descripcion_Ingles, Descripcion_Castellano, Pegi,Pegi_USA, Descripcion_Pegi, Codigo_juego, Lanzamiento, URL, URL_imagen,"
                        + "Argentina, Argentina_Oferta, Argentina_Gold, Argentina_Access,"
                        + "Australia, Australia_Oferta, Australia_Gold, Australia_Access,"
                        + "Brasil, Brasil_Oferta, Brasil_Gold, Brasil_Access,"
                        + "Canada, Canada_Oferta, Canada_Gold, Canada_Access,"
                        + "Chile, Chile_Oferta, Chile_Gold, Chile_Access,"
                        + "China, China_Oferta, China_Gold, China_Access,"
                        + "Colombia, Colombia_Oferta, Colombia_Gold, Colombia_Access,"
                        + "Espanya, Espanya_Oferta, Espanya_Gold, Espanya_Access,"                           
                        + "Hong_Kong, Hong_Kong_Oferta, Hong_Kong_Gold, Hong_Kong_Access,"
                        + "Hungria, Hungria_Oferta, Hungria_Gold, Hungria_Access,"
                        + "India, India_Oferta, India_Gold, India_Access,"
                        + "Inglaterra, Inglaterra_Oferta, Inglaterra_Gold, Inglaterra_Access,"
                        + "Japon, Japon_Oferta, Japon_Gold, Japon_Access,"
                        + "Korea, Korea_Oferta, Korea_Gold, Korea_Access,"
                        + "Mexico, Mexico_Oferta, Mexico_Gold, Mexico_Access,"
                        + "Rusia, Rusia_Oferta, Rusia_Gold, Rusia_Access,"                 
                        + "Singapur, Singapur_Oferta, Singapur_Gold, Singapur_Access,"                            
                        + "Sudafrica, Sudafrica_Oferta, Sudafrica_Gold, Sudafrica_Access,"
                        + "Taiwan, Taiwan_Oferta, Taiwan_Gold, Taiwan_Access,"
                        + "USA, USA_Oferta, USA_Gold, USA_Access"                            
                + ") VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?"
                        + ",?,?,?,?"
                        + ",?,?,?,?"
                        + ",?,?,?,?"
                        + ",?,?,?,?"
                        + ",?,?,?,?"
                        + ",?,?,?,?"
                        + ",?,?,?,?"
                        + ",?,?,?,?"
                        + ",?,?,?,?"
                        + ",?,?,?,?"
                        + ",?,?,?,?"
                        + ",?,?,?,?"                           
                        + ",?,?,?,?"
                        + ",?,?,?,?"
                        + ",?,?,?,?"
                        + ",?,?,?,?"
                        + ",?,?,?,?"
                        + ",?,?,?,?"
                        + ",?,?,?,?"
                        + ",?,?,?,?"
                        + ")")) {

                    ps.setString(1,titulo);
                    ps.setString(2,game.getValues().get(Constants.GOLD));
                    ps.setString(3,game.getValues().get(Constants.THE_VAULT));
                    ps.setString(4,game.getValues().get(Constants.EA_ACCESS));
                    ps.setString(5,game.getValues().get(Constants.OFERTA));
                    ps.setString(6,game.getValues().get(Constants.FECHA_SPOTLIGHT));
                    ps.setString(7,game.getValues().get(Constants.TIPOLOGIA));
                    ps.setString(8,game.getValues().get(Constants.PERTENECE));                                            
                    ps.setString(9,game.getValues().get(Constants.NOTA));
                    ps.setString(10,game.getValues().get(Constants.DESCRIPCION_INGLES));
                    ps.setString(11,game.getValues().get(Constants.DESCRIPCION_CASTELLANO));
                    ps.setString(12,game.getValues().get(Constants.PEGI));
                    ps.setString(13,game.getValues().get(Constants.PEGI_USA));
                    ps.setString(14,game.getValues().get(Constants.DESCRIPCION_PEGI));   
                    ps.setString(15,game.getValues().get(Constants.VALUE_MSSTORE_URL));
                    ps.setString(16,game.getValues().get(Constants.FECHA));
                    ps.setString(17,game.getValues().get(Constants.URL_JUEGO));
                    ps.setString(18,game.getValues().get(Constants.URL_IMAGEN));
                    int contador = 19;
                    for (Map.Entry<String, String> e: countries.entrySet()) {   
                        ps.setString(contador,game.getValues().get(Constants.PRICE_NORMAL + " "+ e.getKey()));
                        contador++;
                        ps.setString(contador,game.getValues().get(Constants.PRICE_OFFER + " "+ e.getKey()));
                        contador++;
                        ps.setString(contador,game.getValues().get(Constants.PRICE_GOLD + " "+ e.getKey()));
                        contador++;
                        ps.setString(contador,game.getValues().get(Constants.PRICE_ACCESS + " "+ e.getKey()));
                        contador++;
                    }
                    ps.executeUpdate();
                }
            } else {
                titulo = game.getName();

                String query = "UPDATE info_XboxOne SET "
                + "Nota = ?, Descripcion_Ingles = ?, Descripcion_Castellano = ?, "
                + "Pegi = ?, Pegi_USA = ?, Descripcion_Pegi = ?, juego = ?, Lanzamiento = ?, URL = ?, URL_imagen = ?,"
                        + "Argentina = ?, Argentina_Oferta = ?, Argentina_Gold = ?, Argentina_Access = ?,"
                        + "Australia = ?, Australia_Oferta = ?, Australia_Gold = ?, Australia_Access = ?,"
                        + "Brasil = ?, Brasil_Oferta = ?, Brasil_Gold = ?, Brasil_Access = ?,"
                        + "Canada = ?, Canada_Oferta = ?, Canada_Gold = ?, Canada_Access = ?,"
                        + "Chile = ?, Chile_Oferta = ?, Chile_Gold = ?, Chile_Access = ?,"
                        + "China = ?, China_Oferta = ?, China_Gold = ?, China_Access = ?,"
                        + "Colombia = ?, Colombia_Oferta = ?, Colombia_Gold = ?, Colombia_Access = ?,"
                        + "Espanya = ?, Espanya_Oferta = ?, Espanya_Gold = ?, Espanya_Access = ?,"                            
                        + "Hong_Kong = ?, Hong_Kong_Oferta = ?, Hong_Kong_Gold = ?, Hong_Kong_Access = ?,"
                        + "Hungria = ?, Hungria_Oferta = ?, Hungria_Gold = ?, Hungria_Access = ?,"
                        + "India = ?, India_Oferta = ?, India_Gold = ?, India_Access = ?,"
                        + "Inglaterra = ?, Inglaterra_Oferta = ?, Inglaterra_Gold = ?, Inglaterra_Access = ?,"
                        + "Japon = ?, Japon_Oferta = ?, Japon_Gold = ?, Japon_Access = ?,"
                        + "Korea = ?, Korea_Oferta = ?, Korea_Gold = ?, Korea_Access = ?,"
                        + "Mexico = ?, Mexico_Oferta = ?, Mexico_Gold = ?, Mexico_Access = ?,"
                        + "Rusia = ?, Rusia_Oferta = ?, Rusia_Gold = ?, Rusia_Access = ?,"                 
                        + "Singapur = ?, Singapur_Oferta = ?, Singapur_Gold = ?, Singapur_Access = ?,"                            
                        + "Sudafrica = ?, Sudafrica_Oferta = ?, Sudafrica_Gold = ?, Sudafrica_Access = ?,"
                        + "Taiwan = ?, Taiwan_Oferta = ?, Taiwan_Gold = ?, Taiwan_Access = ?,"
                        + "USA = ?, USA_Oferta = ?, USA_Gold = ?, USA_Access = ?,"
                        + "DWG = ?, juegos_vault = ?, EA_Access = ?, spotlight = ?, fecha_spotlight = ?"                          
                        + " WHERE Codigo_juego = ?";

                try (PreparedStatement ps = con_actu.prepareStatement(query)) {                                          
                    ps.setString(1,game.getValues().get(Constants.NOTA));
                    ps.setString(2,game.getValues().get(Constants.DESCRIPCION_INGLES));
                    ps.setString(3,game.getValues().get(Constants.DESCRIPCION_CASTELLANO));
                    ps.setString(4,game.getValues().get(Constants.PEGI));
                    ps.setString(5,game.getValues().get(Constants.PEGI_USA));
                    ps.setString(6,game.getValues().get(Constants.DESCRIPCION_PEGI));
                    ps.setString(7,titulo);
                    ps.setString(8,game.getValues().get(Constants.FECHA));
                    ps.setString(9,game.getValues().get(Constants.URL_JUEGO));
                    ps.setString(10,game.getValues().get(Constants.URL_IMAGEN));
                    ps.setString(96,game.getValues().get(Constants.VALUE_MSSTORE_URL));
                    ps.setString(91,game.getValues().get(Constants.GOLD));
                    ps.setString(92,game.getValues().get(Constants.THE_VAULT));
                    ps.setString(93,game.getValues().get(Constants.EA_ACCESS));
                    ps.setString(94,game.getValues().get(Constants.OFERTA));
                    ps.setString(95,game.getValues().get(Constants.FECHA_SPOTLIGHT));
                    int contador = 11;
                    for (Map.Entry<String, String> e: countries.entrySet()) {   
                        ps.setString(contador,game.getValues().get(Constants.PRICE_NORMAL + " "+ e.getKey()));
                        contador++;
                        ps.setString(contador,game.getValues().get(Constants.PRICE_OFFER + " "+ e.getKey()));
                        contador++;
                        ps.setString(contador,game.getValues().get(Constants.PRICE_GOLD + " "+ e.getKey()));
                        contador++;
                        ps.setString(contador,game.getValues().get(Constants.PRICE_ACCESS + " "+ e.getKey()));
                        contador++;
                    }
                    ps.executeUpdate();
                }
            }
```

En teoría por lo general funciona bien, pero hay veces que no. Estando ya el registro incluido, en vez de actualizarme los datos me lo inserta. Lo curioso es que si vuelvo a ejecutar el código para que compruebe el mismo registro, la segunda vez NO me lo inserta, me lo actualiza. Lo único que me he fijado es que el código de la URL que yo introduzco manualmente está en mayúsculas, y que el código de la base de datos está en minúsculas.

No sé si eso puede hacer que la búsqueda me devuelva un resultado negativo. Sino podría añadir la siguiente linea antes de hacer la búsqueda:

```
code.toLowerCase;
```

Lo que no entiendo es cómo puede ser que me ocurra de vez en cuando, y que cuando ocurre, si vuelvo a ejecutar el código con la misma URL me lo actualiza en vez de insertármelo.

Comment: Si, parece que es los que dices tú. Al final tu código es una cadena, si la query busca por "COD_01" y en tu base de datos tienes un registro "cod_01" no lo encontrará, guardará el registro "COD_01" y en la sigeuinte ejecución encontrará el "COD_01" con los datos de "cod_01"

Comment: "Lo que no entiendo es cómo puede ser que me ocurra de vez en cuando, y que cuando ocurre, si vuelvo a ejecutar el código con la misma URL me lo actualiza en vez de insertármelo." Si existe en mayuscula, y en minúscula no lo encuetra, lo da de alta en minúscula. La segunda vez sí lo encuentra en minúscula, porque lo insertó en la llamada anterior.

Comment: Por ahí podes revisar la configuración de la BD y ver si está diferenciando mayúsculas y minúsculas.

Comment: En realidad lo que ha pasado es que el registro ya estaba incluido, con el código en minúsculas. He ido a actualizar la información del registro, y en vez de actualizarla me la ha vuelto a insertar, introduciéndome el código en minúsculas cuando en la URL aparecía en mayúsculas. Es decir, que al volverlo a introducir tendría que volver a agregarme otra linea, porque el código de la URL seguiría estando en mayúsculas, sin embargo me lo actualiza.

Answer (score 0):

La solución pasaría por hacer un `lowerCase` en todos aquellos lugares donde uses el código. Aquí te dejo el ejemplo de uso en el insert.

```
String cod = game.getValues().get(Constants.VALUE_MSSTORE_URL);
cod = cod.toLowerCase();
ps.setString(15,cod);
```

Por supuesto deberías hacer lo mismo en las query de búsqueda:

```
ps.setString(1, code.toLowerCase());
```

Y no deberías olvidarte tampoco de normalizar todos los códigos que ya tienes registrados en la base de datos borrando aquellos que estuvieran duplicados.

Comment: Al introducir el código en la base de datos me lo mete siempre en minúsculas. Me parece curioso pero lo hace automáticamente.

Comment: Has probado a hacer la query siempre con lowerCase?